# How to Manipulate DataObject or increment time?

Tags: manipulate, date-and-time

I'm really new to the Mathematica, anyway my task is to write an application which would show position of ISS on the map but with manipulation/slider option to check position of ISS according to the time (24 hours range) like where it will +2 hours from current time.

So I have for the test a code written by another person to test if I can make it work.

```
    issLocationDisplay[] := Module[{pos, posline, country, city, distance}, 

{pos, posline} = SatelliteData[Entity["Satellite", "25544"], {"Position", "PositionLine"}];

  country = First[GeoNearest["Country", pos]];
  distance = Round[GeoDistance[pos, country], 0.1];

  Panel@Column[{Row[{"ISS Position: ", Style[If[distance <= Quantity[0., "Kilometers"], "Over " <> First[GeoNearest["City", pos]]["Name"] <> ", " <> 
          country["Name"], 
         ToString[
          Row[{"Over the sea ", distance, " od ", country["Name"]}]]],
         Darker[Blue]]}, 

      BaseStyle -> 
       Directive["FontFamily" -> "SansSerif", RGBColor["#497CA4"], 
        Larger, Bold]], 
     GeoGraphics[{Gray, Thickness[.005], 
       Arrowheads[{{0.05, 0.4}, {0.05, 0.13}}], Arrow @@ posline, Red,
        PointSize[.01], Point[pos], Opacity[.1], Black, 
       GeoVisibleRegion[pos]}, GeoCenter -> pos, GeoRange -> "World", 
      ImageSize -> 600]}]]

issLocationDisplay[]
```

My Question is how can I make Manipulation which will work with `SatelliteData` `"Data"` third argument. Do I need to create a List perhaps with 24 hours or there is a function which would help me to achieve it?

Edit: I'm sorry for not creating another thread for this one but I don't want create multiple threads about same problem.

I got the time increment option done but now I'm struggling with implementing my data into `Geographics` there would be a lot of errors if I try to go with `EntityProperty` like this:

```
"Satellite", "Position", "PositionLine", {"Date" -> DateObject[Now] [..]
```

On the other hand when I try different approach from documentation of `SatelliteData` function like this:

```
SatelliteData[Entity["Satellite", "25544"], {"Position", "PositionLine"}, {"Data" -> t}
```

It doesn't work either when I try to pass data from `Position` etc to `Geographics` both by using `With` or creating function with `Module`.

Comment: Be careful not to type "Data" when you mean "Date"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple example that displays the ISS position data inside a `Manipulator` that changes the time parameter:

```
Manipulate[

 SatelliteData[Entity["Satellite", "25544"], 
  EntityProperty["Satellite", "Position",
   {"Date" -> DateObject[Now] + Quantity[dt, "Minutes"]}]],

 {dt, -100, 100, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]
The salient points are the slider and the addition of `DateObjects`.  This slider is bounded at +/-100 and increments in steps of 5.  The time is incremented by adding a `Quantity` to a `DateObject`.

Comment: I managed to create something like this I don't know if there is any critical difference
`Manipulate[SatelliteData[Entity["Satellite", "25544"], 

   EntityProperty["Satellite", "Position", {"Date" -> t}]] DateString[ t], {t, DateObject[], DateObject[] + Quantity[24, "Hours"], 
  Quantity[1, "Hours"]}]`

Comment: @MakiNishikino  There are many ways to do it.  Yours looks good.  To display multiple lines, maybe use `Column @ {  SatelliteData[ ... ] , DateString[t]  }` inside the `Manipulator`.  You can also add your `Plot[ ... ]` inside the `Column`